# What's the best way to use Hashicorp Vault in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication, hashicorp-vault

I want to access secrets stored in Hashicorp Vault in Google Cloud Functions, and am wondering about the best way to authenticate and retrieve a token.

I think ideally I would use the default service account credentials inside the cloud function. Is it possible to use Vault's GCP auth backend and create a signed JWT from the default service account? I'm trying to avoid uploading any kind of credentials as part of the function source.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but that might be because I am not acquainted with Hashicorp Vault. Are you asking if JWT can be generated in Cloud Functions using the default service account?

Comment: Just in case: the whole process of generating JWT tokens is described [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/gcp.html).

Comment: In theory the signJwt process should only work if you are inside and compute engine managed by google (like GAE, GCF or a vm with a gcloud authentication) .
That said I've been trying to use the docs google provides on how to generated a signed request, but cannot do it myself.

Answer (score -1):

I think this project could give you good hints on what you want to do: https://github.com/kelseyhightower/vault-on-google-kubernetes-engine

Tell me if it helps.